# Angular 2 - Typescript - Rx - Interface member undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular2-observables

I have below interface;

```
  export interface IDetail {
  name: string;
  office: string;
  addresses: Address[];
  }

  interface Address{
    street: string;
    zip: number;
  }
```

My service method,

```
 getDetails(id: number): Observable<IDetail> {
 return this._http.get(this._apiUrl+ "/" + id)
  .map((response: Response) => <IDetail>response.json())
  .catch(this.handleError);
```

On component ngOnInit method,

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getDetailsService(id)
    .subscribe(data => {
        this.detail = data;
        console.log(this.detail);
        this.AccessAddress();
    },
    error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
   }

AccessAddress(): void{
//After service call, trying to read addresses member
 let addresses = this.detail.addresses;
}
```

Inside subscribe method, i see output for IDetail in console.

After service call, when trying to read addresses member i am get the below error,
***ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'addresses' of undefined***

On html file, i can able access the address member and display on UI.

```
<div *ngFor="let address of detail.addresses">
   {{address.street}}
</div>
```

Do I need the change interface to class? or I need to initialize the addresses member before accessing it? or something else with Observable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my issue with implementing route resolver. I missed angular fundamentals :-(

Answer (score 0):

So the issue is that when you call

```
    let addresses = this.detail.addresses;
```

addresses is undefined because your service call hasnt returned yet, leaving detail undefined as well.  I would advice setting the code with in your service call and all initializing it to be empty initially

```
   ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getDetailsService(id)
    .subscribe(data => {
        this.detail = data;
        console.log(this.detail);
        let addresses = this.detail.addresses;
       },
       error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
     detail={
      addresses:[]
      }
   }
```

And if you need to, initializing it outside of the service call with an empty input while it loads.

Comment: Service call return data, i can see data through console.log(this.detail).

Comment: It might be returning data, but at that point the error has most likely happened. So while its logging the data being loaded the error has already occurred.      'let addresses = this.detail.addresses;' isnt waiting for the call to be completed.  Try logging console.log(this.detail) right before '    let addresses = this.detail.addresses;
' but outside of the subscribe function

Comment: I tried your suggestion and also edited my original question.

Comment: Still the same error/what is the api returning?  Also are you trying to access this.detail anywhere else and if so could you log that?

Comment: Hey so you have another problem, editing suggestion but you should make sure detail.addresses is initialized in the equation to

Comment: try that @Ahelp . initialize the array to empty while you wait for it the subscribe

Answer (score 0):

You can also call a function from within your successful subscription where you can process addresses.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getDetailsService(id)
    .subscribe(data => {
        this.detail = data;
        console.log(this.detail);
        this.processAddresses();
    },
    error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);

}

processAddresses(){
   //Here you can process adderesses 
   let addresses = this.detail.addresses;
   //...
}
```